# How to send Form Data to DE without hitting submit button using AJAX and AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, ajax, post

**I have a HTML Form with AJAX code**

```
   <html>
   <head></head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script> 

    function fChnage(){
    var zipname = $('#zValue').val();
    var emailname = $('#eValue').val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/123",
    data: { Zip: zipname,Email:emailname },
    dataType: "html",
    async: false,
    });
     });
   </script> 

<body>
 <h2>Home insurance Form</h2><div>
 <form action="https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/123" id="myForm"method="post">
Zip Code:<br>
<input name="Zip" placeholder="Zip Code" type="text" id="zValue" onchange="fChnage()"> 
  Email:<br>
  <input name="Email" placeholder="Email address" type="text" id="eValue" onchange="fChnage()">
  <input type="button" value="Buy" id="btnTest">&nbsp;</form></div> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

**Processing Page**

```
    %%[ 
    var @Zip,@Email 
    set @Zip = RequestParameter('Zip') 
    set @Email = RequestParameter('Email') 

     If Not Empty(@Email) Then
             UpsertData('Updated_form_one_AJAX',1,'Email_address',@Email,'Zipcode',@Zip,)
     EndIf
     ]%%
```

My current code is not working means its not posting any records to DE.
Can i get any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an immediate answer for your script issue, but I have some words of advice and guidance which might save you in the long-term.

You intended script will post to a SFMC cloud page upon every change 
`url: "https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/123",`

This will become very costly (unless you have an agreement with Salesforce we're unaware of); as Salesforce charge by Super Message for each Cloudpage view / visit (not unique visit, but actual hits).

So if your AJAX processing script manages to keep updating the data extension values upon each field change, then you will get a lot of action happening.

A method I did accomplish for a client, who needed a 'Language Changer' on their form i.e. a contact is redirected to a Preference Centre which is in English, they can select a language from a dropdown and it would save the language selection on their profile and refresh the page in their chosen language.

I accomplished this using a function :

```
function LanguageChanger() {
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";     
document.getElementById("submitted").value = "lang_change";    
document.getElementById("FanPref").submit();    
}
```

`LanguageChanger()` was called as an OnChange action in the form:

```
     <select style="text-align: :right;
     float: right;" name="Language" id="Language" onchange="LanguageChanger()">
   <option value="en-GB" %%[IF @language=='en-GB' Then ]%% selected %%[endif]%% >English</option>
   <option value="fr-FR"  %%[IF @language=='fr-FR' Then ]%% selected %%[endif]%%>French</option>       
  </select>
```

My processing page was the same as the form page, and upon Submit / Load there was a conditional statement to see if Language was changed :

```
Set @submitted = RequestParameter("submitted")
Set @Language = IIF(EMPTY(RequestParameter("lang")),'en-GB',RequestParameter("lang"))

/* LANGUAGE CHANGER SUBMIT - this has to be handled separately from a normal submit*/

  IF (@submitted == "lang_change")Then
          var @EmailAddress
          /*If yes then get all post values */
          Set @SubscriberKey = RequestParameter("email")
          Set @EmailAddress = RequestParameter("email")
          Set @Language = RequestParameter("language")


          /* Perform upsert */
          UpsertData('DataExtensionName',1,'EmailAddress', @EmailAddress, 
          'Language', @Language
        )

        Redirect(CloudPagesURL(ABC123,@EmailAddress))
        Endif
```

Hope this helps as an explanation of how I got around the requirement. Again, this solution limits how many page calls are being made - it only loads for when a single field (Language) is changed.

Comment: i agree with you that `Onchange()` method will make multiple calls to cloud page but i have more then 10 fields in my form so i want to capture only the  `email address` and may be `First name `  to re-target them with email **and**  i want to capture `email address` immediately when they enter it.